# wlan0 not showing in ifconfig and "sudo ifconfig wlan0" does not work

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I am new to Kali Linux. When I tried to used my wireless adapter, and then used the `ifconfig` command, it's only showing eth0 and lo. However, when I use `ifconfig -a`, or `iwconfig`, wlan0 does show up. But when I use the command `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, it's showing the following:

`root@kali:~# sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

`SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory`

What should I do?

Comment: This is some serious issue. Sometimes while installing an OS they don't include the dkms. Search for dkms in apt and install for your required driver. Some years ago people have to do it manually by compiling source . But now it is already in the apt repository.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues here.

First there is no point in using `sudo` if you are already root. `sudo` is meant to be used by non-root users that want to do privileged stuff.

Second the `ifconfig` command is obsolete. You should be using the `ip` command instead. Try the following as root `ip link set wlan0 up` (or prepend `sudo` if you are non-root).

Third, it seems that you are missing some firmware. Run `dmesg` in your terminal. All kernel messages will show up and you will need to find for hints on missing firmware related to your wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after fresh arch linux install. In my case this package was missing

> linux-firmware

Simply install it and reboot the system. This might be silly because if you are running the iso image it should be included but it is not guaranteed to be installed.

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware
```

**Arch:**

```
sudo pacman -S linux-firmware
```